# almacenar varios valores en un array

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tengo un campo que se repite muchas veces en una tabla y necesito sacar ese valor repetido para limpiar la base de datos. En una variable estoy almacenando todos esos códigos, entonces en un ciclo `foreach`, pero solo me esta almacenando el ultimo registro, y necesito que todos los que estén repetidos se almacenen.

```
public function scriptBaseDeDatos(){
    $data = $this->script->consultaGenereal();
    
    foreach($data as $codigo){
        $cod1 = $codigo;
        $repetidos = array();
        foreach($data as $cod2){
            if($cod1 === $cod2){                    
                array_push($repetidos, $cod2);
            }
        }         
    }

    print_r($repetidos);

    $this->load->setView('cuerpo', 'scrip_json', $data);  
    $this->load->renderView();
    //$this->load->view('scrip_json',$data);

}
```

Comment: Hola, Qué es $data? Hazle un var_dump y muéstralo por favor.

Comment: array (size=4198)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'codigo' => string 'OEF00001' (length=8)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'codigo' => string 'OEF00002' (length=8)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'codigo' => string 'OEF2019003' (length=10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es porque estás redefiniendo el `array` **$repetidos** en cada ciclo del `foreach`. Es decir, por cada **$data**, haces de nuevo un `array` vacío.

Prueba sacándolo de ahí:

```
public function scriptBaseDeDatos(){
    $data = $this->script->consultaGenereal();
    $repetidos = array();
    
    foreach($data as $codigo){
        $cod1 = $codigo;

        foreach($data as $cod2){
            if($cod1 === $cod2){                    
                array_push($repetidos, $cod2);
            }
        }         
    }

    print_r($repetidos);


    $this->load->setView('cuerpo', 'scrip_json', $data);  
    $this->load->renderView();
    //$this->load->view('scrip_json',$data);

}
```

Comment: Aún así siempre va a encontrar iguales, porque está comparando el mismo array 2 veces.

Comment: Es posible claro, hay que revisar. Solo puntualicé por qué no se estaban agregando datos al array.

Comment: No lo digo por ti, digo en general para qué se vea qué siempre van a salir repetidos. El error lo solucionaste